# Mute Win10 Notifications Python

Tags: python, notifications, mute

I have been working on a script to mute notifications while on specific windows. I am looking for a way to mute or block notifications then unmute them when it is left. How can I do this. This is my current code:

```html
import win32gui
import time
w=win32gui
while (true):
    open_window = w.GetWindowText (w.GetForegroundWindow())
    if (open_window == Minecraft 1.10.2):
```

Thanks

Comment: And what is your question? Is your code working? Not working? Producing an error? Doing some other unwanted behavior? Doing nothing?

Comment: It is working, I am just wondering how I mute notifications.